# Changing link in UiWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have to write very simple application whoes open link in UiWebView but I have a little problem because I want that UiWebView download link from outside data e.g. `http://www.example.com/link.txt` and check link on every run of application. I tried to download data to `NSString`but I don't have any ideas how to use this with UiWebView. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSURLRequest` with the URL you downloaded. Then you can change the WebView's content with `loadRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest)`

**Swift 2.2:**

```
let myURLString = "the url you read from the file"
let url = NSURL(string: myURLString)
let request = NSURLRequest(url)

//assuming, the property webView is the UIWebView you want to change
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

**Objective-C:**

```
NSString * myURLString = @"the url you read from the file";
NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myURLString];
NSURLRequest * request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

//assuming, the property webView ist the UIWebView you want to change
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

More information:

- [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadRequest:)
- [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/initWithURL:)
- [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSURL)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but can you write this in Objective-C or its problem ? :)

Comment: I've added the code for Objective-C. (I did not test both codes. Just wrote them in the browser. So there might be some typos)